# Print letter in cell, array loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have cells in Row 1 be numbered A, B, C...

I have red syntax around this statement meaning syntax is wrong.

Code:

```
For Each In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray() ' goal: to iterate through alphabet
        cells(1, counter).value2=lettter in this array
Next
```

If I get this to work I want to be able to let user enter a variable "shift" which applies Caesarian shift to the letters, so that X is the first column rather than A (shift=23).

Comment: The `for each` syntax is wrong. You need this `For Each variable_name In collection_name` `Next variable_name`. You forgot the variable after `each`. (See the [official help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the fun of it, here is a one-liner:

```
Range("A1:Z1").Value = Split(StrConv("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", vbUnicode), vbNullChar)
```

You can very easliy rewrite it for any permutation of the alphabet.

Comment: A little too long for my liking but more concise overall, will use.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA String is a primitive data type and it has no methods (so you cannot do like that: `"ABC".ToCharArrray()`).

The easiest way to achieve your task is by using regular `For ... Next` loop and function `Mid`:

```
Sub printLetters()
    Const ALPHABET As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To VBA.Len(ALPHABET)
        Cells(1, i).Value = VBA.Mid(ALPHABET, i, 1)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `Const` instead of `dim` for the alphabet?

Comment: @Sifu Because it is not supposed to be changed within this function.